Get trimmed down text from Powershell
I am scraping version information from a website. I am able to get the information, but unable to get it without formatting. Currently targeting the DIV tag with Id j_idt19. Is there a way to get the info from the td withing table with id page_footer. I am unable to get to the specific TD with the text.
I would like to place the result into a csv, and just get the text into a text file as Num.NumNum.NumNumNum
# Retrieve the front page of Reddit
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.somesite.com/index.xhtml"

# Select the titles and URLs of the top stories
$results1 = $response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName(“Div”) | Where-Object {$_.id -eq “j_idt19”} | Select-Object -Property TextContent
$results2 = $response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName(“Div”) | Where-Object {$_.id -eq “j_idt19”} | Select-Object -Property TextContent | Out-String

Write-Output $results
$results1 | Export-Csv -Path “C:\Users\ASTRTW3\Desktop\David_Scripts\URL_TEST5.csv"
$results2 | Out-File -FilePath “C:\Users\ASTRTW3\Desktop\David_Scripts\URL_TEST5.txt"

Html code being scraped
<div id="j_idt19" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-south ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-south" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; inset: auto 5px 0px; width: auto; z-index: 0; height: 26px; display: block; visibility: visible;"><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; height: 22px; visibility: visible;">

  <table id="page_footer" style="width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #cbc3be !important;">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td style="width: 30%;">
        
      </td>

      <td style="width: 40%; text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">1.14.012</span>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 15%; text-align: right;">&nbsp;</td>

      <td style="text-align: right; width: 20px; margin-top: 2px;"><div id="j_idt23" style="width:18px;height:18px;position:fixed;right:130px;bottom:2px"><div id="j_idt23_start" style="display:none"><img id="progressBar" src="/CSDB/resources/images/loader_footer.gif"></div><div id="j_idt23_complete" style="display:none"></div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table></div></div>

csv result
#TYPE Selected.System.__ComObject
"textContent"
"

  
    
      
        
      

      1.14.012
      

      ?

      
      
    
  "

Text result
textContent                                                                           
-----------                                                                           
...                                                                                   

expected result
CSV
#TYPE Selected.System.__ComObject
"textContent"
1.14.012

text
1.14.012


Within that div, you need to drill down to the <span> element which contains the string you are after

I'll assume what you're after is always a version contained in a <span> within a <td>, in which case the code you could use would be:
$response.ParsedHtml.getElementById('j_idt19') | ForEach-Object {
    $ver = $null
    foreach ($td in $_.getElementsByTagName('td')) {
        $td.getElementsByTagName('span') |
            Where-Object { [version]::TryParse($_.textContent, [ref] $ver) } |
            Select-Object textContent
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\csv

